# Exluir texto utilizando python no pandas

Tags: pandas, slice

Estou manipulando um dataframe onde um campo tem conteudos como por exemplo:

```
123.456[7].
```

Estou necessitando pegar a sequencia de caracter do inicio deste campo sem a substring `[7]`, para depois retirar o `.` e converter `int`.

df = dataframe
campo = Público Pagante

Comandos:

```
df['Público Pagante'] = df['Público Pagante'].str.slice(start=0,stop=df['Público Pagante'].str.index("[7]"))

df['Público Pagante'] = df['Público Pagante'].str.replace('.','').astype(int)
```

Está dando erro pois o comando 1 está retrnando NaN.

Código completo da extração:

```
# importando as bibliotecas
import pandas as pd
import requests

# URL de origem dos dados
url = 'https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_finais_da_Copa_do_Mundo_FIFA'

# resuisitar a pagina e guardar a resposta
resposta = requests.get(url)

# obter a resposta em formato html
table = pd.read_html(resposta.text)

# O dataframe será apenas a tabela 1
df = table[0]

# colocar os nomes das colunas com o resultado da primenra linha
df.columns = df.iloc[0]

# Apagar uma linha
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)

# tratando o campo 'Público Pagante' e convertendo para int.
df['Público Pagante'] = df['Público Pagante'].str.slice(start=0,stop=df['Público Pagante'].str.index("[7]"))
df['Público Pagante'] = df['Público Pagante'].str.replace('.','').astype(int)

# mostrando os 5 primeiro registros do dataframe
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Estive resolvendo o mesmo exercício e o comando abaixo funcionou:

```
df["Público Pagante"] = df["Público Pagante"].str.replace('.', '').str.replace("[", '').str.replace("7", '').str.replace("]", '').astype(int)
```

Não ficou elegante, mas resolveu o problema :)